# Can Kubernetes scale down but avoid disconnecting users?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to be able to scale down without disconnecting any users.

This would be especially useful for a stateful application like mine where users connect and stay connected over websockets.

One idea: perhaps it could not allow any new users to a particular pod, then once that pod is empty of users it then shuts that pod down? That way it would wait for users to disconnect on their own time.

Another idea: kubernetes could tell my pod that it wants to shut the pod down, but the pod could respond with a 'snooze' until it's ready to be shut down? In my use case that would mean checking that all of the users in the pod have disconnected.

How would I go about implementing one of these, or another solution to solve the problem?

I’m using Node.js and Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: are you using sticky sessions?

Comment: I'd argue that instead of trying to design a system that guarantees any invariables (e.g. a pod only terminates when all client connections to it finish) it's better to try to design a system resilient to failures, (e.g. if a client gets disconnected - because the pod was terminated - it will try to reconnect). That will also address other failure modes, like unexpected node or pod failures, e.g. because of memory pressure / OOM.

Comment: That makes sense BogdanL, but I don't think it needs to be one or the other. That is, it could be resilient to failure in many ways, and also avoid causing disconnects when trying to scale down.

Comment: mkorbi I edited the question to add that users connect and stay connected over websockets.

Comment: This [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace) could be usefeul. Also as mentioned by BogdanL, your application should manage this kind of failures, you can take a look in [circuit break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern) pattern to improve your application.